# Turn IF/Else Statement into a Variable

Tags: php

Here is the code I'm trying to turn into a variable:

```
<?php if(in_array($locale, $month_first_locales)){
    echo strftime("%B %d, %Y");
}else{
    echo strftime("%d %B %Y");
} ?>
```

I'm just trying to turn this into a `$date` variable so I can add `<?php echo $date; ?>` in my code

how can i?

Comment: just assign it instead of echoing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$date = (in_array($locale, $month_first_locales)) ? strftime("%B %d, %Y") : strftime("%d %B %Y");
echo $date;
```